# Opening a windows relative to its tab in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I've a WPF application that makes use of AvalonDock for opening multiple tabs ...each tab represents a function and has it's own controls .. The single tab is opened via menu.

Sometimes I need to show a window in the current tab and I use the

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
w.Show(); //w.ShowDialog();
```

this opens a popup(/modal) but when I switch the tab (in the case it's not modal) I have the Window still open... what I need is to "force" the window to be shown only in it's tab.

I've tried setting the Owner of the window but when I do

```
 var wnd = Window.GetWindow(docuentPane);
```

I got the main window of the app...

is it possible to do what I want to achieve in WPF? if yes how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite sure what you want.

Comment: suppose I've a tab, in this tab I open a window for inserting some data, I wish to be able to open the 2 tab and not see the window (which is still present in the first tab)